# descriptive statistics with group by in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a sample working code as below. The result should `group` ( based on Species and/or Species2) then print out the `mean` of Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width. I appreciate.

```
    library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

iris$Species2 <- iris$Species

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(inputId ="column",
              label = "Choose Column for Summary",
              choices = c("Species", "Species2"),
              selected = "Species", multiple = T),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    Summarise <-
      iris %>%
      dplyr::group_by(groupby = input$column) %>% 
      summarise( mean1 = mean(iris$Sepal.Length))
    DT::datatable(data = Summarise)
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Expected Answer;

```
a <- iris %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>%
  dplyr::summarise( mean1 = mean(Sepal.Length)); a


  Species    mean1  mean2 
  <fct>      <dbl> 
1 setosa      5.01  5.01
2 versicolor  5.94  5.94
3 virginica   6.59  6.59
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `across` in `group_by` so that you can group by multiple inputs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

iris$Species2 <- iris$Species

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(inputId ="column",
              label = "Choose Column for Summary",
              choices = c("Species", "Species2"),
              selected = "Species", multiple = T),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    Summarise <-
      iris %>%
      dplyr::group_by(across(all_of(input$column))) %>% 
      summarise(mean1 = mean(Sepal.Length))
    DT::datatable(data = Summarise)
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: is there a way to see the results not in the same table but in the separate tables?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you mean.

Comment: if I need group statistics for multiple factors (Species,...Species10) having one result table will be confusing. is this possible to show the tables separately? the first table will show the mean of Species and the second table will show the mean of Species2.

Comment: Sure that should be possible but I think including it in this post would be confusing for future readers. Can you ask that as a new question ?